# Backup camera fuzzy image

Tags: electrical, backup-camera

Been at the dealer this week and enabled a rear cam on uConnect RHB 430N infotainment unit. 
Getting fuzzy / flickering image?

430N: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0jPpNs5Q1E

It shows just fine when I stream the same video signal through WIFIAV (video over WiFi, from the same source, powered in parallel, video out is feeding the two).

WIFIAV: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzkyAiVQ0X8

When camera power is disconnected, blank screen w/Check entire surroundings' title displays just fine.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH0oTXnzpn0

Brought another video source to the vehicle, by looking inside confirmed it has a PAL chip if that might be relevant. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UfC4-ZTr9Q

Same split fuzzy image on the dash 
[image: WIFIAV]

but nothing wrong via WIFIAV 
[image: WIFIAV].

What the issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a video format issue. If your infotainment unit is configured for PAL format. Your backup camera may not be. Is there a switch on the camera unit to change format.

Comparison of formats:

Video Bandwidth: NTSC  4.2MHz    Pal: 5.0 MHz

Vertical Freq:   NTSC  60Hz      Pal:   50Hz
(this could explain flickering)

Horizontal Frequency: NTSC  15.734 kHz  PAL: 15.625 kHz
(this could explain shakiness of image and double images)

Lines/Field: NTSC: 525/60   Pal: 625/50